# Change a column data with a function that takes another column data as input

Tags: function, plsql, calculated-columns

Here is my problem. I have one table with multiple columns. I had to anonymize it (using a dedicated tool, I won't go into detail). Now, the problem is that I have a column, let's say B, that directly depends on another column, let's say A. I encrypted A, so I need to re-compute the whole B column, such as b = f(a) for all b in B, a in A.

**Example** : let's say I work with the following table

```
A  |  B
-------
2  |  3
14 |  2
6  |  1
22 |  9
10 |  13
```

with all values of column A encrypted, but B remains unchanged. Now I need to apply, for instance, this function

```
create or replace function correct_b_column(input number) return number is
begin
    return input * input
end
```

to whole B column to ensure that for all a in A, b in B, I still have b = a² even after encrypting column A.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate which version of Oracle you have, but assuming 11gR1 or greater the best way would be just create column B as [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1#creating-virtual-columns).

```
create table vir_col_b ( a integer 
                       , b integer generated always as ( a*a)  );
```

If the derivation of B is complicated then a function can be used.  
This guarantees B is always set in terms of A. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=afa67043bb76d18dffc24e95d5bc4642).